# Python " ".join() syntax error

Tags: python

I haven't done much with Python, but the code-academy course has seemed to give me some enjoyment however when I have taken my project to the actual python compiler I get an error compiling.  Highly possible that code-academy just hasn't updated to a more recent version, as I've seen here that people have used this previously.

`C:\Python>battleship.py
  File "C:\Python\battleship.py", line 10
    print " ".join(row)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

For some reason I am having issues placing the source in the question, as this is my first question, so ill describe the code.  Using an empty list there is a "board" created to play battleship on, with a for loop that loops through a set range appending < board.append["O"] * 5 >.  Then it loops through each row in the array and then uses < print " ".join(row) >

How can I get by this and is there an alternative way that is better?

Edit: Python version 3.5.2

Comment: Are you using Python 3 by any chance?

Comment: Yes, had just edited it before seeing this comment.  Version 3.5.2

Comment: In that case you need to use `print (" ".join(row))` as Python 3.x changed `print` to be a function, so you have to use parentheses.